# RegEx for replacing all characters apart from numbers

Tags: c#, .net, regex

If I have a string of data with numbers in it. This pattern is not consistent. I would like to extract all numbers from the string and only a character that is defined as allowed. I thought RegEx might be the easiest way of doing this. Could you provide a regex patter that may do this as I think regex is voodoo and only regex medicine men know how it works

eg/

```
"Q1W2EE3R45T" = "12345"
"WWED456J" = "456"
"ABC123" = "123"
"N123" = "N123" //N is an allowed character
```

**UPDATE**: Here is my code:

```
var data = Value.Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
data = data.Select(x => Regex.Replace(x, "??????", String.Empty)).ToArray();
```

Comment: ARe the strings very long?? a for is not an option???

Comment: `"regex is voodoo and only regex medicine men know how it works"`. Not true! It makes a lot of sense once you think carefully about it, piece by piece.

Comment: @katrielalex I do understand the short ones but long ones are tricky!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
String numbersOnly = Regex.Replace(str, @"[^\d]", String.Empty);
```

Using [`Regex.Replace(string,string,string)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7f5w83z.aspx) static method.

[Sample](http://ideone.com/mU9v8)

To allow `N` you can change the pattern to `[^\dN]`. If you're looking for `n` as well you can either apply [`RegexOptions.IgnoreCase`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions.aspx) or change the class to `[^\dnN]`

Comment: Oops! Just realised I need to allow the 'N' character

Comment: @Jon: Updated my answer to allow for `N`.

Answer (score 4):

No need to use regexes! Just look through the characters and ask each of them whether they are digits.

```
s.Where(Char.IsDigit)
```

Or if you need it as a string

```
new String(s.Where(Char.IsDigit).ToArray())
```

---

EDIT Apparently you also need `'N'`:

```
new String(s.Where(c => Char.IsDigit(c) || c == 'N').ToArray())
```

EDIT EDIT Example:

```
var data = Value.Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
data = data.Select(s => 
    new String(s.Where(c => Char.IsDigit || c == 'N').ToArray())
).ToArray();
```

That's kinda horrible -- nested lambdas -- so you might be better off using the regex for clarity.

Comment: Can you use my LINQ to show your answer as IsDigit will only check a character in the string?

Comment: @Jon what? I don't understand your sentence.

Comment: Can you use the code in my question to show how your answer would fit into it

Comment: @Jon done. You might be better off using the regex, just for code clarity.

Answer (score 1):

How about something along the lines of

```
String s = "";
for ( int i = 0; i < myString.length; ){
    if ( Char.IsDigit( myString, i ) ){ s += myString.Chars[i]; }
}
```