# Regex to separate different currencies and numeric value

Tags: c#, regex, currency

I am stuck at separating the numeric value with currency symbols and texts. I have a list where I have values like

$164.5
256.29 SAR
œ3,056.46
121.88 EUR
€156.12

I need to separate the symbol/code of currency and numeric value..

Can anyone help?

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: I was looking into http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17173551/java-regex-split-double-from-string but it just separates the A-Z part with numeric part.. I have special characters as well (currency symbols)

Comment: I'd go with **regex** but of course pattern is **culture dependent**. **Don't** imagine you can do it with a **single regex** (even if you don't consider negative values). Thousands separators (and multipliers) will make it even harder than what you're seeing.

Comment: You could start here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9774323/regex-for-replacing-all-characters-apart-from-numbers

Comment: @Lloyd the comma and decimal point will cause issue..

Comment: @ArsalanAdamKhatri as I said that's a point where you could start, if you simply want someone to write you a regex so you do not have to learn anything then that is up to you.

Comment: @ArsalanAdamKhatri if you're looking for a ready-to-use bunch of code then probably you're in the wrong place. Answers will give you a **hint to write it by your own**.

Comment: Topic is complex and good code is long. As you can imagine: different **currency symbol** (single character and/or text); **different position** for such symbol (sometimes _dynamic_, sometimes not); different symbols for **decimal separator** and **thousands separator**; different **position of thousands separators** (in Japan, for example, you _may_ have separator each 4 digits); different **multipliers** (in some countries currency has multipliers like physical measures).

Comment: Okay, I'm looking for the hints.. Give me a good one! I'm bad at writing regex myself, so thought to get some help here.. If that's a crime, I'm surely in a wrong place.. You see, we help on [SharePoint.stackexchange.com](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/4100/arsalan-adam-khatri) and don't really think that everyone asking question is an expert.. So if anyone of the above need help in SharePoint, I surely won't say learn it yourself :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good resource is: http://www.regexr.com/

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"((?<CurrencySymbol>(?<=\s)[^\d\-+\.,]{1,3}) *(?<CurrencyValue>[0-9\.,]+))|((?<CurrencyValue>[0-9\.,]+) *(?<CurrencyCode>[A-Z]{3}))");

string sss = 
@"$164.5
256.29 SAR
œ3,056.46
121.88 EUR
€156.12";

var matches= r.Matches(sss);

foreach (Match match in matches)
{
      Console.WriteLine("____________ "+match.Value);
      if (match.Groups["CurrencySymbol"].Success) 
         Console.WriteLine("CurrencySymbol: " + match.Groups["CurrencySymbol"].Value);
      if (match.Groups["CurrencyValue"].Success)
         Console.WriteLine("CurrencyValue: " + match.Groups["CurrencyValue"].Value);
      if (match.Groups["CurrencyCode"].Success)
         Console.WriteLine("CurrencyCode: " + match.Groups["CurrencyCode"].Value);
}
```

result:

```
____________ $164.5
CurrencySymbol: $
CurrencyValue: 164.5
____________ 256.29 SAR
CurrencyValue: 256.29
CurrencyCode: SAR
____________ o3,056.46
CurrencySymbol: o
CurrencyValue: 3,056.46
____________ 121.88 EUR
CurrencyValue: 121.88
CurrencyCode: EUR
____________ €156.12
CurrencySymbol: €
CurrencyValue: 156.12
```

Explanation of pattern:

```
((?<CurrencySymbol>(?<=\s)[^\d\-+\.,]{1,3}) *(?<CurrencyValue>[0-9\.,]+))|((?<CurrencyValue>[0-9\.,]+) *(?<CurrencyCode>[A-Z]{3}))
```

`[0-9\.,]+` - maches a digit or coma or dot, at least 1 time

`(?<CurrencyValue>[0-9\.,]+)` - is a named group

`[A-Z]{3}` - maches a string made of exactly 3 uppercase letters (I think all currency codes are like that..?)

`(?<CurrencyCode>[A-Z]{3})` - is a named group

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but currency symbols are not limited to `$|€|œ`

Comment: @ArsalanAdamKhatri oh god i wasn't aware of that! *joking*. i provided an example of the condition pattern. it's up to you to find the currency symbols you're interested in & include them in it: \$|€|œ|£|¥|₩|..... People aren't going to do all your work for you. List of symbols http://www.xe.com/symbols.php

Comment: I ain't supposing people to complete my work.. I needed a more dynamic answer.. and yours is not :)

Comment: @ArsalanAdamKhatri I slept on it and i guess you are right. I think instead of (\$|€|œ|...) group you can use (\b[^\w]{1,3}) but it still isn't going to return the exact correct result

Comment: @ArsalanAdamKhatri this pattern: ((?<CurrencySymbol>(?<=\s)[^\d\-+\.,]{1,3}) *(?<CurrencyValue>[0-9\.,]{2,}))|((?<CurrencyValue>[0-9\.,]{2,}) *(?<CurrencyCode>[A-Z]{3})) should match what you want in a more dynamic way, although it will still return true for values starting with comma or dot: "f.234" or "F ,134". currency symbol is recognised as:"following a white char, not digit, dot,coma,minus or plus, 1 to 3 chars long". I dont know a way in which currency sybols can be further limited, their unicode codes are all over the place.

Comment: Thanks for putting the efforts brother, I have come up with a code solution like the other answer.. I think yours will do the job too, so will mark it correct..

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible solution without a regular expression. It looks for start and end positions of the number included in the string. Any non-whitespace, non-number character is considered to be the currency code. After that it uses the built-in  `Decimal` parser to find the number. I have added the `CultureInfo` parameter to make it possible to parse the decimal correctly depending on the globalization settings.

```
static bool TryParseNumberWithCurrency(string data, CultureInfo culture, 
    out decimal number, out string currency)
{
    //remove whitespace
    data = new string(data.Where(c => !char.IsWhiteSpace(c)).ToArray());
    int i = 0;
    //find start position of number
    while (i < data.Length && !IsValidNumberChar(data[i])) i++;
    int startOfNumber = i;
    //find end position of number
    while (i < data.Length && IsValidNumberChar(data[i])) i++;
    int endOfNumber = i;
    //currency symbol may be before or after, but not both
    if (startOfNumber > 0 && endOfNumber < data.Length)
    {
        number = default(decimal);
        currency = null;
        return false;
    }
    currency = startOfNumber > 0 ? data.Substring(0, startOfNumber) 
        : data.Substring(endOfNumber);
    return decimal.TryParse(data.Substring(startOfNumber, endOfNumber - startOfNumber),
        NumberStyles.Number, culture, out number);
}
```

It uses this simple helper method to define valid characters for a number:

```
private static bool IsValidNumberChar(char c)
{
    return char.IsDigit(c) || c == '.' || c == ',' || c == '-';
}
```

To use this method:

```
string testValue = "€156.12";
decimal num;
string currency;
if (TryParseNumberWithCurrency(testValue, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out num, out currency))
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} => {1}, {2}", testValue, num, currency);
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Parse failed for {0}", testValue);
}
```